# Error: Type "SVGAnimatedLength' has no call signatures" when calling from class

Tags: javascript, typescript, d3.js

I am working on Vue project with D3.js, TypeScript and Vue Property Decorator. I wanted to draw a heatmap but I get an error at when I wanted to call `x()` or `y()` function in return for a computed position of each cell in the heatmap. It throws the error

> Type "SVGAnimatedLength" has no call signatures.

This is how I init my chart variables

```ts
  private svg: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, HTMLElement, any>
  private x: d3.ScaleBand<string>
  private xAxis: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, HTMLElement, any>
  private y: d3.ScaleBand<string>
  private yAxis: d3.Selection<SVGGElement, any, HTMLElement, any>
```

this is where it causes error

```ts
this.svg.selectAll()
  .data(this.getData().filter((datum: HeatmapData) => this.betweenTwoDates(datum)))
  .enter()
  .append('rect')
    .attr('x', function(d: HeatmapData) {
      return this.x(d.dayNumber)
    })
    .attr('y', function(d: HeatmapData) {
      return this.y(d.timeOfDay)
    })
    .attr('cx', 1)
    .attr('cy', 1)
    .attr('width', this.x.bandwidth())
    .attr('height', this.y.bandwidth())
```

at

```ts
.attr('x', function(d: HeatmapData) {
  return this.x(d.dayNumber)
})
```

the error happens at `return this.x(d.dayNumber)` stating `Type "SVGAnimatedLength" has no call signatures`. Same goes for `.attr('y', ...)` too.

The `this` at `this.x()` has a type of `SVGRectElement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a nice example of when to actually use [arrow functions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) in favor of regular functions! Because regular functions—like in your code—establish their own `this` scope you no longer have access to the `this` scope you are interested in, namely the scope of your surroungding class.

Many D3 methods are called with `this` set to the current DOM element:

> with *this* as the current DOM element (*nodes*[*i*])

To be able to use your class instance's methods by referring to them using `this` you can just use an arrow function which does not come with its own scope but captures the scope of its surrounding context, i.e. your class/instance. Your methods should therefore look like this:

```
.attr('x', d => this.x(d.dayNumber))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `this` has a type of SVGRectElement because it is inside a regular anonymous function. In D3, methods for manipulating nodes replace the `this` context with the own DOM Element that is being manipulated, in your case a `<rect>`. The `<rect>` nodes don't have x or y methods, hence the type error.

Replacing the anonymous functions with arrow functions [preserves the `this` from the outside](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions):

```js
.attr('x', (d: HeatmapData) => {
          return this.x(d.dayNumber)
 })
 .attr('y', (d: HeatmapData) => {
          return this.y(d.timeOfDay)
 })
```

Now, the `this` inside the function is the same `this` from the outside, which in your case is the class that contain svg, x, xAxis, y and yAxis.